# GeometricScene doesn't quite work in v13.0.1

Tags: computational-geometry

I used `GeometricScene` in v12.x quite a bit in some project and although the feature was experimental it was reliable before. I recently upgraded to v13.0.1 and had to rely on the feature again, but now it doesn't quite work.

This, for example, produces an expected result:

```
RandomInstance@GeometricScene[
  {
    c1 -> {-2, 0},
    c2 -> {2, 0},
    c3
  },
  {c3 ∈ Line[{c1, c2}]}
]
```

[image: GeometricScene]

But then the same code with just the numbers changed doesn't work:

```
RandomInstance@GeometricScene[
  {
    c1 -> {23.6352, 11.0083},
    c2 -> {23.8438, 11.035},
    c3
  },
  {c3 ∈ Line[{c1, c2}]}
]
```

which is weird. Did I miss something? Were there any changes to `GeometricScene` I'm not aware of? Or is this just a bug? (I understand that the feature is still experimental after all.)

Comment: `RandomInstance@
 GeometricScene[{Rationalize[c1 -> {23.6352, 11.0083}, 0], 
   Rationalize[c2 -> {23.8438, 11.035}, 0], 
   c3}, {c3 \[Element] Line[{c1, c2}]}]` fails too in 13 on Windoes 10.